# How can i make a background image act like img with img-fluid like in the picture

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[Display of the 2 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyi6C.png)
The issue is on the first row, that it's not displayed properly and it's not responsive to resize like the second row. I can't figure it out how to make it like that tried everything but nothing seems to work.
The reason i am tring to do this is that the text and the elements on the picture doesn't stay on the same position on resize.
Image size is width 420px, height 466px; [board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqAH4.png)

```html
   <head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">      <!-- BOOTSTRAP 5.1 CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">  <!-- BOOTSTRAP Icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/solid.css">                    <!-- font-awesome icon -->
   </head>
   
   <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="ms-4 me-4 mt-3">
            <div class="row">
                
                <div style="position: relative; background-image: url('/images/Board 1.png'); background-size: cover; background-position: center center;height: 100%;" class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="top-left text-dark"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></span>
                    <span class="top-right">New</span> 
                    <!--product description -->
                    <div class="">BILLABONG</div>
                    <div class="font-weight-bold">Deep Ocean Surfing Board</div>
                    
                </div>
                <div style="position: relative; background-image: url('/images/Board 1.png'); background-size: cover; background-position: center center;" class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="top-left text-dark"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></span>
                    <span class="top-right">New</span> 
                    <!--product description -->
                    <div class="">BILLABONG</div>
                    <div class="font-weight-bold">Deep Ocean Surfing Board</div>
                    
                </div>
                <div style="position: relative; background-image: url('/images/Board 1.png'); background-size: cover; background-position: center center;" class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="top-left text-dark"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></span>
                    <span class="top-right">New</span> 
                    <!--product description -->
                    <div class="">BILLABONG</div>
                    <div class="font-weight-bold">Deep Ocean Surfing Board</div>
                    
                </div>
                <div style="position: relative; background-image: url('/images/Board 1.png'); background-size: cover; background-position: center center;" class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="top-left text-dark"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></span>
                    <span class="top-right">New</span> 
                    <!--product description -->
                    <div class="">BILLABONG</div>
                    <div class="font-weight-bold">Deep Ocean Surfing Board</div>
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="mt-5"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div style="position: relative;" class="col-md-3">
                    <img  class="img-fluid" src="/images/Board 5.png" alt="">
                    <span class="top-left text-dark"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></span>

                    <div class="">BILLABONG</div>
                    <div class="font-weight-bold">Deep Ocean Surfing Board</div>
                    
                </div>
                <div style="position: relative;" class="col-md-3">
                    <img  class="img-fluid" src="/images/Board 6.png" alt="">
                    <span class="top-left text-dark"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></span>

                    <div class="">BILLABONG</div>
                    <div class="font-weight-bold">Deep Ocean Surfing Board</div>
                    
                </div>
                <div style="position: relative;" class="col-md-3">
                    <img  class="img-fluid" src="/images/Board 7.png" alt="">
                    <span class="top-left text-dark"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></span>

                    <div class="">BILLABONG</div>
                    <div class="font-weight-bold">Deep Ocean Surfing Board</div>
                    
                </div>
                <div style="position: relative;" class="col-md-3">
                    <img  class="img-fluid" src="/images/Board 8.png" alt="">
                    <span class="top-left text-dark"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></span>

                    <div class="">BILLABONG</div>
                    <div class="font-weight-bold">Deep Ocean Surfing Board</div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really hard to do without defining the size of the div that contains everything. I would set the padding-top to be the size I wanted the image to be, and width to define the box's size, then I would use media queries to resize the boxes at certain sizes, then use `background-size: contain` instead of cover.

```css
.product-container {
  position: relative; 
  background-size: contain; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  padding-top: 315px; /* the width and height of the image, plus the actual padding, 15px*/
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="ms-4 me-4 mt-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="product-container" style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/300/300');">
                    <span class="top-left text-dark"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></span>
                    <span class="top-right">New</span> 
                    <!--product description -->
                    <div class="">BILLABONG</div>
                    <div class="font-weight-bold">Deep Ocean Surfing Board</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If it were me, though, I'd stick with `<img>` so that you can let it resize without writing media queries.

Comment: I tried the first time to do with <img> but the problem is that i have some text over the image( new text with border around it) and a heart for likes if I resize the heart stay there on the left but the new text which is on the right part of the picture will leave the picture allot on the right.